# Permissions ... how to make a folder undeleteable?

Tags: unix, permissions, file-permissions, freebsd, freenas

On FreeNAS (FreeBSD) ... I'm trying to make a folder 'undeleteable'.

I logged in as root. I created a folder called `test` and `chmod` it to `700 (rwx------)`. Owner is `root`, group is `wheel`.

Then I log in as a user called `john`, which is part of group `bbstaff` -- and I am able to rename AND delete folder `test`. Shouldn't that be impossible?

I thought the `w` permissions prevented renaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sledgehammer solution to this sort of problem is to make the directory immutable.  This should be done with extreme care, as it's not a very common operation, so if you do it it's a very good idea to leave a file behind in the directory, with a giant warning:

```
# /some/directory/VAR_HAS_BEEN_MADE_IMMUTABLE.WARNING
```

Once you've done that:

```
# chflags schg /some/directory/var
```

You'll find it no longer can be moved, deleted, or altered, even by root until you've flipped the flag back.

Note that this is the BSD approach to the linux command chattr +i

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-protect-file-with-immutable-bit.html

Answer (score 1):

Google offers many answers, including [ths one](https://serverfault.com/questions/125320/chmod-to-prevent-deletion-of-file-directory), which says "setting the sticky bit on the parent directory will only allow deletion by the directory owner.

chmod +t /some/dir/ParentDir

Look at the usage section on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit for more information about Sticky bits"

[This one](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1402205.html) also advokates using the sticky bit.

Thirdly, [this page](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Permissions.html) says "When a directory is made sticky, it adds a special security feature. It prevents someone from deleting or renaming files in a directory unless they own the file.".

Looks like that's your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the lead ... actually, for FreeBSD, the sticky bit is set using a `1` prefix before the permissions, e.g., `chmod 1777 /path/file`. But what I want to do is 'lock' a particular directory, not ALL the directories. Is that possible?

Comment: +1 I am not sure that I understand "lock' a particular directory, not ALL the directories" - do you mean lock the directory, but not its sub-direcctories e.g  lock /home/a but not /home/a/b or /home/a/c etc ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want `john` to be able to read/write/rename/delete everything that is in the same folder as `test` EXCEPT for `test`. I want him to only SEE `test` but NOT be able to delete/rename/open it. Same goes for all other users in group `bbstaff`.